# Create Google line graph from existing array when call IP

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have created a web server on ESP8266 that uses Google gauge to display current temperature data and line graph to display previous data. The gauge and line graph will update as new data come in. Everything works well and when I call the IP the line graph will display and start to populate. The problem is that every IP call the line graph starts with no data and populates all over again because when dataTable is initialized it is returning a new empty data table. Can anyone make a suggestion on creating a line graph from the existing data array in the datatable when make IP call? Thanks.

Code to update line graph:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart','gauge']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart(){
      //Create opening gauges 
        var gaugeData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Label', 'Value'],
          ['Room 1', 0],
          ['Room 2', 0]
         ]);
       
        var gaugeOptions = {
          width: 800, height: 240,
          redFrom: 90, redTo: 100,
          yellowFrom:75, yellowTo: 90,
          minorTicks: 5
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(gaugeData, gaugeOptions);
        
      //Obtain new temperature data and update gauge and line graph
       
      setInterval(updateValues, 3000); 
       
      function updateValues() {
      //Obtain Room 1 temperature and update Google Gauge
      
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
      Room1temp = parseFloat(this.responseText);
      gaugeData.setValue(0, 1, Room1temp);
      chart.draw(gaugeData, gaugeOptions);
      }
    };
     xhttp.open("GET", "/Room1temp", true);
     xhttp.send();
    
      //Obtain Room 2 temperature and update Google Gauge
      
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
      Room2temp = parseFloat(this.responseText);
      gaugeData.setValue(1, 1, Room2temp);
      chart.draw(gaugeData, gaugeOptions);
      }
    };
     xhttp.open("GET", "/Room2temp", true);
     xhttp.send();
    };
      
    //Update Google line chart with timestamp and Room 1 & 2 temperatures
    
     var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
       data.addColumn('datetime', 'Time');
       data.addColumn('number', 'Room 1');
       data.addColumn('number', 'Room 2');

     setInterval(updateGraph, 3000); 
       
      function updateGraph() {
       //create timestamp
      let date = new Date();
      var Year = date.getFullYear();
      var Month = date.getMonth();
      var Day = date.getDate();
      var Hour = date.getHours();
      var Min = date.getMinutes();
      var Sec = date.getSeconds();

      //Update line graph
      if(data.getNumberOfRows()<5){
       data.addRows([
         [new Date(Year,Month,Day,Hour,Min,Sec), parseFloat(Room1temp), parseFloat(Room2temp)]
         ]);

      } else {
       var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
       data.addRows([
         [new Date(Year,Month,Day,Hour,Min,Sec), parseFloat(Room1temp), parseFloat(Room2temp)]
         ]);
       data.removeRow(0);
       }

       var options = {
       title: 'Temperature Data',
       pointSize: 8
     };

      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
      chart.draw(data, options); 
     
     };  //End function updateGraph

    } // End function drawChart

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width:600px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto"></div>
    <div id="curve_chart" style="width:1400px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: will you please share the rest of code, specifically the IP call?

Comment: here is the entire code;

Comment: The IP call is just the IP address of the ESP8266 Board I type in the web browser. Its not operating currently but can if necessary

Answer (score 0):

try making the IP calls in succession, waiting for each to complete,
before continuing to the next and updating the charts.

see following snippet...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart', 'gauge']
}).then(function () {
  //Create opening gauges
  var gaugeData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Label', 'Value'],
    ['Room 1', 0],
    ['Room 2', 0]
   ]);

  var gaugeOptions = {
    width: 800, height: 240,
    redFrom: 90, redTo: 100,
    yellowFrom:75, yellowTo: 90,
    minorTicks: 5
  };

  var gaugeChart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  gaugeChart.draw(gaugeData, gaugeOptions);

  // line chart
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('datetime', 'Time');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Room 1');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Room 2');

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

  var options = {
    title: 'Temperature Data',
    pointSize: 8
  };

  //Obtain new temperature data and update gauge and line graph
  setInterval(updateValues, 3000);

  function updateValues() {
    //Obtain Room 1 temperature and update Google Gauge
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
        var Room1temp = parseFloat(this.responseText);
        gaugeData.setValue(0, 1, Room1temp);
        gaugeChart.draw(gaugeData, gaugeOptions);

        //Obtain Room 2 temperature and update Google Gauge
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
            var Room2temp = parseFloat(this.responseText);
            gaugeData.setValue(1, 1, Room2temp);
            gaugeChart.draw(gaugeData, gaugeOptions);

            //Update line graph
            if(data.getNumberOfRows()<5){
              data.addRows([
                [new Date(), parseFloat(Room1temp), parseFloat(Room2temp)]
              ]);
            } else {
              data.addRows([
                [new Date(), parseFloat(Room1temp), parseFloat(Room2temp)]
              ]);
              data.removeRow(0);
            }
            chart.draw(data, options);
          }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", "/Room2temp", true);
        xhttp.send();
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "/Room1temp", true);
    xhttp.send();
  };
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately the data obtained previously still will not appear when make new call to URL. The line graph continues to repopulate starting with no data. I think I will need to save temp data from Ardunio ino to CSV file and then use jjquery-csv library and google.visualization.arrayToDataTable() to import data